# How To Display Value from Theme Options Field in Front End Template?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I put this code into my functions.php https://gist.github.com/corvannoorloos/4703066 and it work nice.

Now I want to display value from **Sample Select Options** filed in some front-end templates.

How can I do that?
I tried [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

```
<?php echo get_option( 'sample_select_options', true); ?>
```

but it return number 1 no matter what is selected.

Comment: At first glance, you need to make sure you call the correct option. Looking at the Gist, there is a `_s_` prefix to the option. Since `_s_simple_select_options` is an array, you might need a foreach loop to deal with multiple values.

Comment: Hi @Strap1. Thank you for the advice. I am not related to php so I am trapped here. 
I found this post http://aquoid.com/news/tutorials/wordpress-theme-options/w-theme-options-setting-and-retrieving/

There is a code snippet to retrive the options. Is that near to what I need?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to display it like this:

```
<?php $options = get_option( 'your_registered_option' ); echo $options['sample_select_options']; ?>
```

Replace **your_registered_option** with the name you gave in functions php for **register_setting();**

Hope this helps

Comment: This may have worked in 2017/2018.  But, it did not work for me in 2020 with WordPress 4.9.8.  The way registration/save works has changed a bit.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (March 2020).

In the PHP of your front end page, add:

```
settings_fields("my_settings_group");
```

Note that "my_settings_group" should be replaced with the name you gave the option group in your "register_setting()" function on the backend.

Then when you want to display an option from that settings group, use this code in your HTML:

`<?php echo esc_attr(get_option("my_option_01")); ?>`

Replacing "my_option_01" with the actual name of the option you want to insert.